# Things painted on awt Canvas show up for half a second and then disapear

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt

I wrote this short piece of code. I want to show a row of rectangles on the canvas on my frame. As mentioned in the title, it shows up and then disappears. I can't seem to find my mistake. There are no exceptions.  What have I done wrong?

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameWindow {
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private JPanel content;
    
    public GameWindow(int fieldSize) {
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Nonogramm");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        
        content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(null);
        
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBounds(200, 200, 600, 600);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.setVisible(true);
        
        content.add(canvas);
        
        drawField(fieldSize, canvas);
        
    }
    
    private void drawField(int fieldSize, Canvas canvas) {
        Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 600; i += 600/fieldSize) {
            g.fillRect(i, 0, 600/fieldSize-1, 600/fieldSize-1);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        
        g.dispose();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: A GUI component is redrawn many times in response to various events, such as mouse cursor movements, window movement and resizing, other windows being moved, *etc*..  Your code paints on the `Canvas` only once, when the `GameWindow` to which it belongs is initialized.  If you want to perform custom painting then override `paintComponent()` and put the appropriate code there.  That way it gets called everytime the component is repainted.

Comment: `canvas.getGraphics()` so not how you do custom painting. See [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) which has a really good example of how it should be used.  The only reason to use `Canvas` is to provide low level access to the painting workflow (also know as direct paint), this is some what more complex from a developer point view then dealing with Swing custom painting

Comment: If you don't need the "as close to the metal" access, you should consider making use of the Swing custom painting workflows.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details